# extra line of output in printf statement

Tags: c, printf, output

I'm trying to take a character as input, and give its ascii value as output until the user gives 0 as input. It works, but there is always an extra ascii value of 10 being displayed. what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Welcome to ASCII:\n");
    char input;
    while(input != 48){
        scanf("%c", &input);
        printf("ascii: %d\n", input);
    }
    printf("done\n");

}
```

output

```
Welcome to ASCII:
e
ascii: 101
ascii: 10
h
ascii: 104
ascii: 10
l
ascii: 108
ascii: 10
0
ascii: 48
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 is the ASCII value for `'\n'`, the newline character generated when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You could add a check for that character and not print its value.

Also it's good style to use `'0'` instead of writing the ASCII value 48.

```
while (input != '0') {
    scanf("%c", &input);

    if (input != '\n') {
        printf("ascii: %d\n", input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ASCII value of 10 is the [new line character](http://www.asciitable.com/).  You're hitting `Enter` between your characters, which is why this is printed.